# How i can create String comparator through lambda?

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8, comparator

I am trying to sort list of string through my own comparator. I saw the below template for list of developers.

```
//lambda
listDevs.sort((Developer o1, Developer o2)->o1.getAge()-o2.getAge());
```

My code: (this is giving me compile error)

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();  
Collections.sort(s, (String a, String b)-> {
    return a.length() > b.length()
});
```

This code is not compiling. Can someone help me what is wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: You should better use `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)`

Comment: Issue was I was returning boolean, return type is int.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn’t change the fact that `s.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));` is preferable, just like the original example should have been `listDevs.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Developer::getAge));` Using minus for comparators is a bad habit. It works here, as the values are never negative, but when sticking to the pattern for all numerical comparators, you will write broken comparators some day, as the difference between two `int` values can be larger than the value range of `int`, leading to overflows. You can use `Integer.compare(x, y)` instead or just use `comparingInt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Arrays.sort` is used for sorting `Arrays` not for `Collection` objects, use [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) to sort `ArrayList`

```
Collections.sort(s,(a,b)->a.length()-b.length());
```

And corresponding lambda expression is wrong  `(String a,String b)-> a.length() > b.length()` which returns Boolean value. Where [Comparator.compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) should return `int` value. And also the type of the parameters can be explicitly declared or it can be inferred from the context.

```
int compare(T o1, T o2)
```

You can also use [List.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-)

```
s.sort((a,b)->a.length()-b.length());
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 unrelated problems with your code:

[1] There are two ways to write lambdas.

You can either write a single expression serving as the return value:

```
s.sort((a, b) -> a.length() - b.length());
```

Or you can involve a code block; but if you do that, return (and semicolons) have to show up:

```
s.sort((a, b) -> {
    return a.length() - b.length();
});
```

Generally if you can make it work with a single expression, just do that; it's shorter. In your example you're using braces (so, the second form), but you don't have the `return` keyword nor the required semicolon.

Also, the types of the lambda arguments are optional. Generally if from context it is clear, just omit these: `(a, b) -> a.length() - b.length()`

[2] a comparator should return 0 if the arguments are equal, a negative number (any negative number, it doesn't matter which one) if a is 'smaller' than b, and a positive number if a is 'larger' than b. You are returning a boolean (you are using a greater than sign; the result of that expression is 'true' or 'false'; you need a number instead.

The solution seems trivial here: use minus instead.

[3] a bonus tip: There are utility methods for comparing based on field: `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)` will do what you want in a way that is easier to read and less error prone. Also, instead of `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` you can just write `list.sort(comparator)`; easier on the eyes, shorter, and more idiomatic.

Let's put it all together:

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();  
s.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
```